# Sharing an ember-data model between two routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

If I…

1. Have two resources defined:

   ```
   this.resource('activity');
   this.resource('notes');
   ```
2. And one model defined:

   ```
   App.Note = DS.Model.extend({

   });
   ```

How do I specify that each endpoint returns a list of resources that should be stored as Notes, as opposed to one set being stored as Activities and another as Notes?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this in the `model` hook of your routes. You'd do the following:

```
App.NotesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      return this.store.findAll('note');
   }
});

App.ActivityRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      return this.store.findAll('note');
   }
});
```

Comment: I've understood that much is possible, but the issue (as I understand it) is that your example would still hit '/notes' in ActivityRoute. I actually need to hit '/activity' and '/notes' because they return different data, but both endpoints return Note models. Does that make sense?

Comment: Nope, `App.ActivityRoute` is (by definition) '/activity'

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: not the application route, the API route. Setting the model to this.store.findAll('note') will still query "//api.myserver.com/notes", correct?

Comment: Yes, it will. Why do you need two different API endpoints for the same  model?

Comment: Not the same model, per se, since they're just list endpoints. To be more specific, in my scenario '/api/activity' and '/api/user/:id/notes' both return lists of notes, but an entirely different set. The former returns recently created notes by all users, and the latter returns notes owned by that user. That being said, the results of each endpoint should still be stored by Ember as "Note" models. This is what I need to accomplish.

Comment: Unfortunately specifying custom api endpoints in Ember Data is not trivial. The most straightforward thing to do is to use `find({user_id: userId})` and then implement the query on your backend

Comment: Otherwise you'd have to override the `buildURL()` function of the `RESTAdapter` (and possibly the `find`/`findAll` functions), but that may get messy quickly

Answer (score 0):

Ember shares data by either using:

1. Ember *store*, as **service**
2. Using **Controllers** to talk (communicate data) to each other

See Diagram

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|    Ember Route                       Ember Route               |
|          +                                 +                   |
|          |                                 |                   |
|          v                                 v                   |
|    Ember Controller   <----------->  Ember Controller          |
|          +                                 +                   |
|          |                                 |                   |
|          v                                 v                   |
|    Ember Component(s)                Ember Component(s)        |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```